# Java-Threads ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I have made a program (for teaching myself purposes) with threads, which is calculating multiplication of elements of an array , using 2 threads. But I get for both threads an **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**. The error looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" Exception in thread "Thread-0" Executing multiplying of last2elements
          java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
          at FirstPart.run(FirstPart.java:12)
          java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
          at SecondPart.run(SecondPart.java:10)
```

Java Code :

FirstPart.java

```
public class FirstPart extends Thread {
    int multiply = 1;
    static int n;
    static int[] v = new int[n];

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Executing multiplying of first "+MultiplyDemo.cap1+"elements"); 
        for(int i = 1; i <= MultiplyDemo.cap1; i++) {
            multiply = multiply * FirstPart.v[i];
            System.out.println("Multiplication is "+ multiply);
        }

    }
}
```

SecondPart.java:

```
public class SecondPart extends Thread {
    int multiply = 1;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Executing multiplying of last " + (FirstPart.n - MultiplyDemo.cap1) + "elements"); 

        for(int i = MultiplyDemo.cap1;i <= FirstPart.n; i++) {
            multiply=multiply*FirstPart.v[i];
            System.out.println("Multiplication is "+multiply);
        }
    }
}
```

MultiplyDemo.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;


public class MultiplyDemo {

    public static int cap1;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("introduceti numarul de elemente din vector:");
        FirstPart.n=s.nextInt();

        int []v=new int[FirstPart.n];
        System.out.println("Elementele vectorului sunt");
        for(int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
            v[i]=s.nextInt();         
        cap1=FirstPart.n / 2;

        FirstPart thread1=new FirstPart();
        SecondPart thread2=new SecondPart();

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        try { // wait for completion of all thread and then sum
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join(); //wait for completion of MathCos object 
            double z = thread1.multiply + thread2.multiply;
            System.out.println("produsul elementelor este" +z);
        } 
        catch(InterruptedException IntExp) {
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays indexes are 0-based; if an array has a size of `n` valid indexes are in range `0..n-1`.
All your `for` loops check with a `<=` instead of using `<` and this is why you are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Usually a "for loop" on arrays has this form:

```
Object[] array = new Object[size];
for(int i = 0;i < array.length;i++) {
  ..
}
```

In this way you can never exceed the size of array

Comment: I understand what I am doing wrong, but could you please show me what am I supposed to do ? It would mean the world to me !

Comment: replace `i <= FirstPart.n` with `i < FirstPart.v.length` and `i <= MultiplyDemo.cap1` with `i < FirstPart.v.length` and you don't get exception anymore.

Comment: Just a question: are your teaching yourself threads and you are in trouble writing a indexed loop on arrays? I think you should rethinking about your learning program steps...

Answer (score 0):

Make your both for loop to this :

```
for(int i=0; i < MultiplyDemo.cap1; i++)
```

And PS : Please post question in proper format so that it will be easy for someone to help with.

Comment: but it won't do what is's supposed to , the SecondPart class should continue multiplying from the MultyplyDemo.cap1 until the end(second half of the array)

Answer (score 0):

`MultiplyDemo.cap1` is bigger than you `n` leading to your for loop trying to access an index that does not exist:

```
for(int i=1;i<=MultiplyDemo.cap1;i++)
    multiply=multiply*FirstPart.v[i]; // Misses index 0 and tries to go to index n, when n-1 is max
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "n" defaults as 0, and so your v array has 0 length.

This is why you're getting index out of bounds.

In your main method, you're initalizing a new "v" variable. Keep in mind that this "v" array is not the same static "v" array as in "FirstPart"

Comment: no, the v array is initialized in decleration, while n is 0. in main, a different instance (also called v) is initialized.

Comment: sorry I meant that `n` was initialized in main

Comment: still, not true. main initializes a different instance, unrelated to FirstPart.v which is initialized in decleration before main does anything.

Comment: as per above code in Main `FirstPart.n=s.nextInt();`  `n` is a static variable - how can it be a different instance?

Comment: n is initialized in main AFTER v is already initialized, and so the initialization of n in main doesnt affect anything.

Comment: Now I understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

FirstPart.v is still an empty array. You are assigning the value to n from the main() method and initializing values to a local array which doesn't affect FirstPart.v

Comment: but I don't know how to alter the code, if I move the n,v, declarations to my main I can't have acces to them I get errors. I am a beginner , so I don't know what should I do in this case.